# Using Rcpp to expose a constructor that takes a pointer to an object as a parameter

Tags: c++, oop, rcpp

I have the following very simple code that defines a class B that takes as a parameter a pointer to an object of class A.

The code works perfectly if I compile it as standalone C++, but I haven't been able to expose class B using Rcpp.  I must be doing something wrong in the line `.constructor<A>()` near the end.  Have tried all the combinations of &, *, etc. and nothing works.  I'm lost after many hours of trying.  Any ideas are welcome.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class A {
public:
  A(int val_) { val = val_; }
  int val;
};

class B {
public:
  B(A& ptr_) { ptr = &ptr_; }
  int getval() { return (this->ptr->val); }
  A *ptr;
};

RCPP_MODULE(module_cpp) {
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<A>("A")
    .constructor<int>()
    .field("val", &A::val)
    ;

    class_<B>("B")
    .constructor<A>()
    ;
}
```

Comment: It's been a while I thought about this, but are you sure we allow _inheritance_ this way?  I think most Rcpp Modules use is simpler and does just one layer (possibly templated as I do in Rcpp Annoy).

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: I haven't seen an Rcpp example of this, but this is a common use of objects.  For example, A could be a city and B could be a person.  Then one can ask things like "what is the temperature in the city where this person lives?".  B does not inherit from A, but just has a pointer to A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try to be stubborn: Your constructor for `B` expects a reference to an `A`, so we should expose it as such, i.e. `.constructor<A&>()`. Doing so I get the error

> `invalid user-defined conversion from ‘SEXP’ {aka ‘SEXPREC*’} to ‘A&’`

Basically we want to create something that's callable within R (the constructor for `B`), but we can only use `SEXP` as type for the arguments. And currently it is unknown how to convert between `SEXP` and `A&`. This sort of conversion would be the task of `Rcpp::as` (and `Rcpp::wrap` for the reverse), which are covered in the Rcpp-extending vignette. For Rcpp Modules, we can take the shortcut provided by `RCPP_EXPOSED_AS` and friends, c.f. section 2.2.11 in the Rcpp-modules vignette.

Here a complete example with added verification code:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class A {
public:
    A(int val_) { val = val_; }
    int val;
};

class B {
public:
    B(A& ptr_) { ptr = &ptr_; }
    int getval() { return (this->ptr->val); }
    A *ptr;
};

RCPP_EXPOSED_AS(A);

RCPP_MODULE(module_cpp) {
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<A>("A")
        .constructor<int>()
        .field("val", &A::val)
    ;

    class_<B>("B")
        .constructor<A&>()
        .method("getVal", &B::getval)
    ;
}

/***R
a <- new(A, 42)
b <- new(B, a)
b$getVal()
*/
```

Output:

```r
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('61898230.cpp')

> a <- new(A, 42)

> b <- new(B, a)

> b$getVal()
[1] 42
```

Comment: Nice.  Rcpp Gallery write-up to preserve it / give it more exposure?

Comment: @Dirk. I just realized I have written several times about `RCPP_EXPOSED_*` before. It would make sense to write that up for the gallery. Let's see if I can find some motivating example ...